# FTP Connection with a WAMP server

Tags: wamp, ftp

I downloaded and installed the latest version of WAMP package to my PC, and what I want to do is to connect it using FTP.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Apache, the server that is included in WAMP, is purely a web server, not a FTP server.  You need to set up an additional FTP server in order to be able to FTP into it.  One such server is the [Filezilla Server](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server), but there are other options too.

Answer (score 0):

As [farfromhome stated](https://superuser.com/questions/239605/ftp-connection-with-a-wamp-server/239689#239689), the WAMP server hasn't got an FTP server included. If you do want a complete package without installing a seperate FTP server such as [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/), I recommend removing the WAMP server and installing complete package like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). XAMPP also includes FileZilla, but will set it up for you. However do note that XAMPP isn't meant for production purposes but development purposes.